# accept multiple types and numbers of parameters scala

Tags: scala, types, parameters, constructor

I have the something akin to the following code (only with more parameters) in a program I am developing:

```
class Particle {
   //variables
   def this(position: Position2D, velocity: Vector2D) = {
   this()
   //constructors
   }

   def this(xPos: Double, yPos: Double, magnitude: Double, angle: Double) = {
   this(new Position2D(xPos, yPos), new Vector2D(magnitude, angle))
   }
}
```

And I would like to make it so that the program is able to accept the `Position2D` object for the first parameter and two `Doubles` for the second parameter, or two `Doubles` for the first parameter and a `Vector2D` object for the 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter, without creating more `this` statements for each combination of parameters. I know that it's possible to use something like:

```
def this(posObj: Either[Position2D, Array[Double]], velObj: Either[Vector2D, Array[Double]]) = {...}
```

And then test to see what type `posObj` and `velObj` are; however, I was curious if there was a way to do this without requiring the 2<sup>nd</sup> part of the `Either` to be just one item such as an `Array`, so that you could initialize `Particle` like the following:

```
val a = new Particle(new Position(3, 6), 30, 5)
val b = new Particle(3, 6, new Vector2D(30, 5))
val c = new Particle(new Position(3, 6), new Vector2D(30, 5))
val d = new Particle(3, 6, 30, 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, the constructors are rigid in the sense that the number of parameters (assuming you don't want them in a Seq) for a method (or constructor in this case) has to be quite specific.

Potentially by enclosing the naked pairs in a Tuple2 and creating a typeclass instance to unpack each this would be possible, but it would be an order of magnitude more complicated than just adding the constructors.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution for this would be to create your class with 2 parameter lists in the constructor, one taking the `Position2D` and one taking the `Vector2D` and then create implicit conversions from `Tuple2` to both of them:

```
case class Vector2D(x: Double, y: Double)
case class Position2D(x: Double, y: Double)

implicit def tuple2Vector2D(t: (Double,Double)): Vector2D = Vector2D(t._1, t._2)
implicit def tuple2Position2D(t: (Double,Double)): Position2D = Position2D(t._1, t._2)

class Particle(val v: Vector2D)(val p: Position2D)

scala> new Particle(1.1,3.1)(6.1,0.3)
res15: Particle = Particle@15a74f84

scala> new Particle(new Vector2D(1.1,3.1))(6.1,0.3)
res16: Particle = Particle@47283198

scala> new Particle(1.1,3.1)(new Position2D(6.1,0.3))
res17: Particle = Particle@2571e404

scala> new Particle(new Vector2D(1.1,3.1))(new Position2D(6.1,0.3))
res18: Particle = Particle@38be7bc0
```